# Mass and density function Calculus II Problem

Tags: calculus, parametric

A thin metal plate lies over the portion of the cylindrical surface $y^2 + z^2 = 4$ for $z ≥ 0$ between $1 ≤ x ≤ 4$. The density of the plate is given by $f(x,y,z) = z$.

How do I calculate the mass of the plate? I'm pretty confused. Thank you!

Comment: Can anybody help? Thank you!